# How to understand logic of Tradingview PineScript "?" if statement

Tags: pine-script

I am having troubles with understanding PineScript `?` statement logic, there is such function in Pinescript on TradingView:

```
updown(s) =>
    isEqual = s == s[1]
    isGrowing = s > s[1]
    ud = 0.0
    ud := isEqual ? 0 : isGrowing ? (nz(ud[1]) <= 0 ? 1 : nz(ud[1])+1) : (nz(ud[1]) >= 0 ? -1 : nz(ud[1])-1)
    ud
```

I have tried my best to crack the logic of the `?` expression above, but I am not sure if I am correct.
I have written the logic in pseudo code, but I need someone to tell me if I am correct.

```
if s == s.shift(1):
    ud = 0
else:
    if s > s.shift(1):
        if (nz(ud[1]) <= 0:
            ud = 1
        else:
            nz(ud[1]) + 1)
    else:
        if nz(ud[1]) >= 0:
            ud = -1
        else:
            nz(ud[1]) - 1)
```

If I am correct or wrong please tell because I have no idea myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?:` is called [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator).

```
condition ? valueWhenConditionIsTrue : valueWhenConditionIsFalse
```

You can write the below statement:

```
ud := isEqual ? 0 : isGrowing ? (nz(ud[1]) <= 0 ? 1 : nz(ud[1])+1) : (nz(ud[1]) >= 0 ? -1 : nz(ud[1])-1)
```

as

```
ud := if (isEqual)
    0
else
    if (isGrowing)
        if ((nz(ud[1]) <= 0)
            1
        else
            nz(ud[1])+1)
    else
        if ((nz(ud[1]) >= 0)
            -1
        else
            nz(ud[1])-1)
```